# VB.Net Split word document into separate documents(pagebreak as delimiter)

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, automation

A word document has several pages. How to split this pages into separate documents using VB.Net ?

I wish to automate this process.

I used ms tutorial for basic learning: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383
But i do not know how to find page breaks in a document and move content of that page to separate document.

Comment: Have you looked at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825254/word-automation-detect-if-page-break-is-necessary) it is for C# but should give you an idea. and also take a look at this [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/vstudio?query=word%20page%20breaks&rq=meta:Search.MSForums.ForumID(0e69520a-0af0-4085-a8c4-c5f21ce20e01)+site:microsoft.com&rn=Visual+Studio+Tools+for+Office+Forum)

Comment: thank you. but it did not helped me much. I also searched and found a solution. I do not know whether it is great solution, but it works. Solution is posted below as answer. If you find anything that can be improved please post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
Private Sub ParseWordDoc(ByVal Filename As String, ByVal NewFileName As String)
    Dim WordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
    Dim BaseDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim DestDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

    Dim intNumberOfPages As Integer
    Dim intNumberOfChars As String
    Dim intPage As Integer

    'Word Constants
    Const wdGoToPage = 1
    Const wdStory = 6
    Const wdExtend = 1
    Const wdCharacter = 1

    'Show WordApp
    WordApp.ShowMe()

    'Load Base Document
    BaseDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename)
    BaseDoc.Repaginate()

    'Loop through pages
    intNumberOfPages = BaseDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages").value
    intNumberOfChars = BaseDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Characters").value

    For intPage = 1 To intNumberOfPages
        If intPage = intNumberOfPages Then
            WordApp.Selection.EndKey(wdStory)
        Else
            WordApp.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToPage, 2)
            Application.DoEvents()

            WordApp.Selection.MoveLeft(Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1)
        End If

        Application.DoEvents()

        WordApp.Selection.HomeKey(wdStory, wdExtend)
        Application.DoEvents()

        WordApp.Selection.Copy()
        Application.DoEvents()

        'Create New Document
        DestDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        DestDoc.Activate()
        WordApp.Selection.Paste()
        DestDoc.SaveAs(NewFileName & intPage.ToString & ".doc")
        DestDoc.Close()
        DestDoc = Nothing

        WordApp.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToPage, 2)
        Application.DoEvents()

        WordApp.Selection.HomeKey(wdStory, wdExtend)
        Application.DoEvents()

        WordApp.Selection.Delete()
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next

    BaseDoc.Close(False)
    BaseDoc = Nothing

    WordApp.Quit()
    WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Credit goes to "[**Jay Taplin**](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/445644-how-do-i-extract-page-word-insert-into-new-word-document-using-vb)"